# How to rename theorem (or lemma) in Beamer?

Tags: beamer, theorems

I usually write theorem as follows:

```
\begin{theorem}[abc]
...
\end{theorem}
```

Then the title will be `Theorem (abc)`. I would like to name it differently, for instance, "Theorem of abc", "ABC theorem"... Could anyone tell me how to do it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Customizing theorem name](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12913/customizing-theorem-name)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can redefine the `theorem begin`, and `theorem end` templates. In the following example, I suppressed the numbering and the parentheses, and added "of" between the theorem name and the theorem additional note:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{theorem begin}
{%
\begin{\inserttheoremblockenv}
{%
\inserttheoremheadfont
\inserttheoremname
\ifx\inserttheoremaddition\@empty\else\ of\ \inserttheoremaddition\fi%
\inserttheorempunctuation
}%
}
\setbeamertemplate{theorem end}{\end{\inserttheoremblockenv}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{theorem}[Fermat]
Test theorem.
\end{theorem}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You can use the block env.

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]\frametitle{}
\begin{block}{Any Title}
  Simmons Hall is composed of metal and concrete.
\end{block}
\end{frame}
```

[image: Use of block function to create boxes]