# Is there a \renewtheorem equivalent of \renewcommand, using amsthm and not ntheorem?

Tags: macros, theorems, amsthm

Suppose I have a theorem that is defined a certain way, as follows.

```
\newtheorem*{mytheorem}{Foo}
```

And I want to redefine it another way further down in my document, as below.

```
\newtheorem*{mytheorem}{Bar}
```

What is the easiest way to go about this?

I would like something like this, but I get `undefined control` sequence on `\renewtheorem`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{thmTemp}{Foo}
\begin{thmTemp} First one.  \end{thmTemp}

\renewtheorem*{thmTemp}{Bar}
\begin{thmTemp} Second one.  \end{thmTemp}
\end{document}
```

When I run `pdflatex` on this, I get the following:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.10     \renewtheorem
                  *{thmTemp}{Bar}
```

I am avoiding `ntheorem` because it does not preserve the theorem styles defined by `amstheorem`, even when the `amsthm` option is passed to it, and I would prefer not to redefine those styles.

Comment: Have you tried `\renewtheorem`? It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.  That way we would know which packages you are using as some solutions may be package specific.

Comment: Try replacing `amsthm` with `ntheorem`.

Comment: @PeterGrill, There's actually a specific reason I want to use amsthm and not ntheorem. I prefer not to redefine `\theoremstyle{definition}` among others.

Comment: And yes, I have tried the [amsthm] option to ntheorem, but it does not achieve the desired effect.

Comment: You add this requirement to the question.

Comment: @PeterGrill, As requested, I have added the requirement.

Comment: Thanks. Would be good also if you explained exactly what the issue with using `ntheorem` is. It is not obvious to me, but perhaps to those who are more knowledgeable it would be. Once your objection is understood perhaps there is a way to use `ntheorem` that overcomes that objection.

Comment: Errrr... I was about to give a possible helpful answer along the lines of `\let\thmTemp\relax\newtheorem*...`, but I object to using the `\new...` and `\renew...` family as in-document (as opposed to preamble) commands, so I won't.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz, please give your answer. I have tried something similar but could not get it to work.

Comment: This question is actually closely related to my other question here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103011/how-can-i-define-a-new-environment-which-limits-the-scope-of-newtheorem-command?rq=1 and I think a helpful answer here might resolve that too.

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you specified more closely what you mean by 'redefine it another way'... How do you expect the redefined theorem environment to behave? Do you simply want to change the heading and continue numbering with the previous counter? Or do you also want to change the style of the theorem?

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65951

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rather than redefining the environment each time, I would define a wrapper:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{inner}{\innerheader}
\newcommand{\innerheader}{}
\newenvironment{defi}[1]
 {\renewcommand\innerheader{#1}\begin{inner}}
 {\end{inner}}

\begin{document}
\begin{defi}{Foo}
First one.
\end{defi}

\begin{defi}{Bar}
Second one.
\end{defi}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 15):

If one systematically needs different theorems definitions in the same documents, egreg approach is convenient. But many of us might have a  `mymath.tex` with common shortcuts and settings, which is a very likely place for the `\newtheorem`  definitions, and occasionally one  might want to override these definitions, e.g. to change the theorems' locale.

In these cases, editing  `mymath.tex` or mantaining a second  one is inconvenient and prone to errors, much  better to  plug a new `altthm.tex` in the main document overriding theorem definitions.
To this end, we need a `\renewtheorem` command:

```
\makeatletter
\def\renewtheorem#1{%
  \expandafter\let\csname#1\endcsname\relax
  \expandafter\let\csname c@#1\endcsname\relax
  \gdef\renewtheorem@envname{#1}
  \renewtheorem@secpar
}
\def\renewtheorem@secpar{\@ifnextchar[{\renewtheorem@numberedlike}{\renewtheorem@nonumberedlike}}
\def\renewtheorem@numberedlike[#1]#2{\newtheorem{\renewtheorem@envname}[#1]{#2}}
\def\renewtheorem@nonumberedlike#1{  
\def\renewtheorem@caption{#1}
\edef\renewtheorem@nowithin{\noexpand\newtheorem{\renewtheorem@envname}{\renewtheorem@caption}}
\renewtheorem@thirdpar
}
\def\renewtheorem@thirdpar{\@ifnextchar[{\renewtheorem@within}{\renewtheorem@nowithin}}
\def\renewtheorem@within[#1]{\renewtheorem@nowithin[#1]}
\makeatother
```

Use as the `\renewtheorem` as the standard `\newtheorem`:

```
\renewtheorem{env_name}{caption}[within]
\renewtheorem{env_name}[numbered_like]{caption}
```

It works with `amsthm`.

The MWE, excluding the `\renewtheorem` definition, is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\begin{thm}
My theorem ...
\end{thm}

\renewtheorem{thm}{Proposition}[section]
\begin{thm}
My theorem ...
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, do _not_ tell me you submit papers using some sort of `mymacros.tex`. If you do, I truly hope I won't meet the papers.

Comment: @yo': Hmm... sorry to disappoint you, but  LaTeX most relevant feature is macros, which avoid repetitive typing. Putting all of them in the preamble, or even worse in the body of text, creates clutter and defeats the whole purpose of LaTeX being focused on content, rather than presentation. Anyway, unless you are involved publishing a journal, you are not supposed to read the sources producing the papers. 

P.S. in case you might be interested, I fixed a bug in the code.

Comment: Well, if people define 100 macros in their "preamble file" and then use 5 of them in the article, it's anything but convenient. (btw, I am involved in journal typesetting...)

Comment: @yo' from your perspective, you are right. From the author  perspective, you are absolutely wrong. But I understand that journal typesetting is the key part of Science.

Comment: @antonio Can your trick be made to work with \newtheorem*{thm*} ?

Comment: Easier: use `\newcommand*{\deftheorem}[3]{\@ifundefined{#1}{\newtheorem{#1}{#2}[#3]}{}}` and replace `\newtheorem{type}{Name}[within]` by `\deftheorem{type}{Name}{within}` in your `mymath.tex`, and be sure to issue any occasional `\newtheorem` _before_ loading your style file.

Comment: Also, I know from experience that researchers who maintain a personal style file ends up with better (La)TeX code (easier to read, more accurate and elegant typesetting), which should in the end ease the work of publishers. The latter should actually take this into account before imposing class files loading packages known for conflicting with many others.

Answer (score 6):

Reducing @antonio's answer: you can get a more robust result with only the first block of code; instead of a `\renewtheorem`, one can just as easily use a `\cleartheorem` as below:

```tex
\makeatletter
\def\cleartheorem#1{%
    \expandafter\let\csname#1\endcsname\relax
    \expandafter\let\csname c@#1\endcsname\relax
}
\makeatother
```

In my view, the extra complexity and dependency on `\newtheorem` (which precludes the use of re-defining a theorem with `\declaretheorem` from `thmtools`, and assumes additional things about the inner workings of the theorem package & its interface) is not justified over the extra line of code to get the desired effect:

```tex
% suppose you're using \declaretheorem
\usepackage{amsthm, thmtools}

% this could be included from a separate file
\declaretheorem[name=Definition,numberwithin=section]{defn}

\cleartheorem{defn}
\declaretheorem[name=RevisedDefinition]{defn} % no error here
```

---

**Edit**: for further convenience, one can clear all theorems with one command, so that there is no more than one line of redundant code:

```
% define this in the preamble in between \makeatletter and \makeatother
\def\clearthms#1{ \@for\tname:=#1\do{\cleartheorem\tname} }
```

Then in the document:

```
% clear the previous definitions
\clearthms{defn,example,theorem,coro,prop}


% now execute all of the commands exactly as if the preamble didn't have them...
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{coro}{Corollary}[theorem]
\newtheorem{prop}[theorem]{Proposition}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}{section}
\declaretheorem[qed=$\square$]{example}
```

Comment: Underrated answer, this worked for me a treat!