# New environment issues arguments xargs.Missing Number and Illegal unit of measure

Tags: amsmath, amsthm, optional-arguments, arguments, changepage

I'm trying to make a general environment for delineating sections of math with indented bodies, (proofs, definitions, etc).

I found that using the 'adjustwidth' environment in the 'changepage' package was what I needed for the indentation.

To make the general environment I followed along to the answer from this link:

[Is there a \renewtheorem equivalent of \renewcommand, using amsthm and not ntheorem?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103013/is-there-a-renewtheorem-equivalent-of-renewcommand-using-amsthm-and-not-ntheo)

The syntax I desire is the following:

`\begin{env-name}{Header}{Counter}[Punctuation][Note][indentation-size]` for numbered environments

`\begin{env-name}{Header}[Punctuation][Note][indentation-size]` for unnumbered environments

and would produce the following: (unnumbered)

{Header}[Punctuation] [Note] \n

[indent with indentation-size] body text...

I'm pretty new to latex2e (or whatever) language, but I checked the environment definition and couldn't see what could be wrong.

Below is my package file containing what I believe is minimum requirement to reproduce the error.

```
\RequirePackage{changepage}
\RequirePackage{amsthm}
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{amsfonts}
\RequirePackage{xargs}

%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                        Package Options/Commands
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Blank commands used for a abstract math environment

\newcommand{\mathsecheader}{}
\newcommand{\mathsecpunc}{}

% reset blank commands

\newcommand{\reset}{%
\renewcommand{\mathsecheader}{}%
\renewcommand{\mathsecpunc}{}%
}

%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                                Main body
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newtheoremstyle{augmented_remark}
{0.5\topsep}
{0.5\topsep}
{\normalfont}
{}
{\itshape}
{}
{}
{\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\mathsecpunc\thmnote{ #3}\newline}

\theoremstyle{augmented_remark}
\newtheorem*{tremark_unnumbered}{\mathsecheader}

\newenvironmentx*{remark_unnumbered}[4][2={:},3={ },4={0pt},usedefault]%
{\ignorespaces%
\renewcommand{\mathsecheader}{#1}%
\renewcommand{\mathsecpunc}{#2}%
\begin{tremark_unnumbered}[#3]%
\begin{adjustwidth}{#4}{#4}%
}
{\end{adjustwidth}\end{tremark_unnumbered}\reset\ignorespacesafterend}
```

Below is the actual .tex file I'm using to compile the document.

```
% Testing document for proof formatting
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{dummy_test}

\begin{document}

\begin{remark_unnumbered}{Claim}[.][Hello][2ex]
hello
\end{remark_unnumbered}

\end{document}
```

I'm not sure if this would be useful but I am using TeXMaker with MikTex to compile. Below are the two error printouts that I am receiving:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
\relax
l.8 ...in{remark_unnumbered}{Claim}[.][Hello][2ex]
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again>
\relax
l.8 ...in{remark_unnumbered}{Claim}[.][Hello][2ex]
Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc,
cm, mm, dd, cc, nd, nc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one!
I'll assume that you meant to say pt, for printer's points.
To recover gracefully from this error, it's best to
delete the erroneous units; e.g., type `2' to delete
two letters. (See Chapter 27 of The TeXbook.)
```

POST SOLUTION REMARK:

The marked solution fixed the errors and I found that in order to have the body text to be on the next line `\hfill` was added after `\begin{tremark_unnumbered}[#3]`. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last-but-one argument to `\newtheoremstyle` must be a length.

```latex
\newtheoremstyle{augmented_remark}
  {0.5\topsep}
  {0.5\topsep}
  {\normalfont}
  {}
  {\itshape}
  {}
  {0pt} %   <---------
  {\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\mathsecpunc\thmnote{ #3}\newline}
```

However, I have several doubts about having three “optional” arguments that are actually mandatory. At least you should switch the first and second optional arguments.

By the way, `\newline` does nothing at all. And you can remove `\ignorespaces` and `\ignorespacesafterend`.