# How to make "Theorem 1.1" into "1.1 Theorem"?

Tags: numbering, theorems, newtheorem

Usually when using `amsthm`, we get something like `Theorem 1.1`, `Corollary 1.2`, `Definition 1.3`, etc. But how can I put the number before the name "Theorem" and "Corollary", that is to say, to obtain things like `1.1 Theorem`, `1.2 Corollary`, `1.3 Definition` or `(1.1) Theorem`, `(1.2) Corollary`, `(1.3) Definition`?

My current codes in this part are

```
\theoremstyle{theorem}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{exercise}[theorem]{Exercise}
\newtheorem{problem}[theorem]{Problem}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem*{remark}{Remark}
```

How can I adjust this? Thank you all for your answers and help!

P.S. I'm so sorry if this question has been asked in TeX.SE, yet I tried a lot searching here and gained nothing.

Comment: @Zarko Yes, that helps! Thank you! :)

Comment: With the `ntheorem` package, you just have to ask for the `change` style.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `\swapnumbers` command in the `amsthm` package is designed for exactly this task:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\swapnumbers
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter title}

\begin{theorem}
Text.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That is much more simpler!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I have found [Theorem style like (1.1 Theorem) and custom theorems like (1.2 Intermadiate Value Theorem)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204200) quite useful. Here are my adapted code:

```
\newtheoremstyle{theorem}% name %TeX.SE 204200
  {}%         Space above, empty = `usual value'
  {}%         Space below
  {\itshape}% Body font
  {}%         Indent amount 
  {\scshape}% Head font
  {.}%        Punctuation after head
  {12pt}% Space after head: \newline = linebreak
   {\def\temp{#3}\ifx\temp\empty\textbf{\thmnumber{#2 }}\thmname{#1}\else\thmnumber{#2}\thmnote{#3}\fi}%         Head spec
   
\newtheoremstyle{definition}% name %TeX.SE 204200
  {}%         Space above, empty = `usual value'
  {}%         Space below
  {}% Body font
  {}%         Indent amount 
  {\scshape}% Head font
  {.}%        Punctuation after head
  {12pt}% Space after head: \newline = linebreak
   {\def\temp{#3}\ifx\temp\empty\textbf{\thmnumber{#2 }}\thmname{#1}\else\thmnumber{#2}\thmnote{#3}\fi}%         Head spec


\theoremstyle{theorem}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{exercise}[theorem]{Exercise}
\newtheorem{problem}[theorem]{Problem}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{convention}[theorem]{Convention}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem*{remark}{Remark}
```