# How to make theorem like one on the picture

Tags: theorems

I want create theorem like this one:[image: theorem]
pharagraph symbol before arabic number, then dot, then theorem name, then subsection with dot and no \newline at the end. "Na to żeby iloczyn nieskończony" is part written in theorem. I have tried many times.
I found this topic: [Theorem style like (1.1 Theorem) and custom theorems like (1.2 Intermadiate Value Theorem)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204200/theorem-style-like-1-1-theorem-and-custom-theorems-like-1-2-intermadiate-valu)
Copied code with definition and guess how it works with reverse engineering, but still my output doesnt look like I want. Any idea how to make this?!

```
\documentclass[12 pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}

\usepackage{polski,enumerate,amsmath,amssymb, multicol,mathtools,ragged2e,amsthm}
\newcounter{mycounter}


\usepackage[a4paper,
            bindingoffset=0.2in,
            top=1in,
            bottom=1in,
            footskip=.25in]{geometry}

\setcounter{page}{104}
\swapnumbers
\newtheoremstyle{theorem}% name
  {}%         Space above, empty = `usual value'
  {}%         Space below
  {\itshape}% Body font
  {}%         Indent amount 
  {\bfseries}% Head font
  {.}%        Punctuation after head
  { }% Space after head: \newline = linebreak
   {$\S\;${#1}\ifx\temp\empty\thmnumber{#2}\else \thmnumber{#2}\thmnote{ #3}\fi}%         Head spec
\theoremstyle{theorem}
\newtheorem{theo}{Twierdzenie}
\begin{document}

\begin{theo}lorem ipsum
\end{theo}
\end{document}
```

Thats short version of my code including all that interferes theorem.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sry, copied wrog from editor. Post fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider using a different theorem package, like `ntheorem`, which makes custom markup a bit easier, imho anyway.

For example:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\newtheoremstyle{mytheorem}{%
    %style without optional argument, ##2 for number, ##1 for theorem name
    \item\normalfont\textbf{\S\;##2.\;##1\;\arabic{subsection}.\;}\itshape
}{%
   % style with optional argument
    \item\normalfont\textbf{\S\;##2.\;##1\;\arabic{subsection}\;(##3).\;}\itshape
}
\theoremstyle{mytheorem}
\newtheorem{theo}{Twierdzenie}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{theo}{96}
\setcounter{subsection}{117}

\begin{theo}
Na to żeby iloczyn nieskończony
\end{theo}
\end{document}
```

[image: ntheorem example]

Not sure if that's what you meant by "subsection", but hopefully you can figure out how to tweak it if need be.

Comment: Gr8 man, do you know how to make curved font normal? Not counting this your answer is just PERFECT.
I think also about using diffrent styles in diffrent theorems.

Comment: bcs \theoremstyle{mytheorem} is global. Am I right?

Comment: "make curved font normal"? Do you mean you don't want italics? Just leave off the `\itshape`. `\theoremstyle{mytheorem}` will be in effect until you issue another `\theoremstyle{...}` command before a `\newtheorem{...}`.