# How can arguments be used inside headstyle with thmtools?

Tags: theorems, thmtools

I'm trying to define something like the named theorems in [Customizing theorem name](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12913/customizing-theorem-name) except using `thmtools`.
As far as I understand, the headspec is to be provided in the key `headstyle` to `\declaretheoremstyle`. However, the following mwe produces the error

```
Illegal parameter number in definition of \thmt@tmp. ...eadstyle={{\thmnote{#3's }#1}}]{namedStyle}
```

Of course I could use `\newtheoremstyle` instead of `\declaretheoremstyle`, but I would prefer not to, since I'm using `thmtools` anyway, and would rather not repeat the built-in defaults when possible. And the thmtools syntax just looks generally cleaner.

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheoremstyle[headstyle={\thmnote{#3's }#1}]{namedStyle}
\declaretheorem[style=namedStyle, title = Theorem]{named}

\begin{document}

Now let us present that most famous of all theorems.

\begin{named}[Fred]
All odd numbers are prime.
\end{named}

\end{document}
```

Most of the mwe is copied from [Loop Space's answer to the above question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12943).

Comment: Effectively you are trying to access `#1` within `#1`, this is an error. The What are the values/contents of `#1` and `#3` ?

Comment: As far as I understand, when `\begin{named}` is processed, `#1` is assigned `Theorem` (as per the `title` key), `#2` is assigned the current value of the associated counter and `#3` onwards are the optional arguments passed.

Comment: Note that LoopSpace's answer doesn't use `\declaretheoremstyle`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within `\declaretheoremstyle` you refer to the parameters `#1`, `#2` and `#3` used in `\newtheoremstyle` as `\NAME`, `\NUMBER` and `\NOTE`.

However, `\NOTE` already receives a formatting, so we need to remove it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\makeatletter
\declaretheoremstyle[
  notebraces={}{},
  notefont=\bfseries,
  headformat=\let\thmt@space\@empty\NOTE's \NAME,
]{namedStyle}
\makeatother

\declaretheorem[style=namedStyle, title = Theorem]{named}

\begin{document}

Now let us present that most famous of all theorems.

\begin{named}[Fred]
All odd numbers are prime.
\end{named}

\end{document}
```

There's no option for changing `\thmt@space`, so I used a hack.

[image]

The rules are generated by `showframe`, just to check for no indentation.

Comment: I somehow missed the paragraph about `\NAME`, `\NUMBER` and `\NOTE` in the `thmtools` documentation. However, this looks clumsier than using `\newtheoremstyle`, so I'll probably stick to that.